# Глупая задача с доменом wordpress

Tags: wordpress, домен

Заказчик в админке wp изменил текущий домен на новый домен, который не зарегистрирован. Нет его в сущности. Знаю глупо. Естественно, что все доступы до админ панели упали. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нужно редактировать, чтобы вернуть старый адрес сайта?
Доступы к хосту и бд мне предоставили

Comment: в бд заменить хост

Comment: https://misha.agency/wordpress/sql-queries-domain.html

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0_WordPress

Comment: @ZaArs перестаньте советовать вредный пост от Рудрастых. Он разрушит базу, если в базе есть сериализованные данные, содержащие заменяемый url.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress/767562#767562

Answer (score 0):

Ищите в файловом менеджере корневую папку сайта, а дальше wp-config.php, там находите такие строчки кода и меняете их:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://site.ru');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://site.ru');
```